# Using convolutional layers in lasagne with OpenCL

Tags: python, opencl, theano, lasagne

I have an AMD graphic card, so I have to use OpenCL. After a long time installing I almost get it working, and the only thing I am unable to do is to use convolutional layers. I get an error:

> AssertionError: AbstractConv2d Theano optimization failed: there is no implementation available supporting the requested options. Did you exclude both "conv_dnn" and "conv_gemm" from the optimizer? If on GPU, is cuDNN available and does the GPU support it? If on CPU, do you have a BLAS library installed Theano can link against?

So, is there a way to use convolutional layers in lasagne on GPU using OpenCL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[The lasagne docs](http://lasagne.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/layers/conv.html) note that on compilation on GPU, it will use a [cuDDN](https://developer.nvidia.com/cudnn) implementation, and if this fails it will fall back to a CPU based implementation. Unfortunately, there seems to be no way to use lasagne with a card only supporting OpenCL.